# Solving the GBM SDE: $()=_t_t+_tS_t_t$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

G'day, I am trying to solve for the Geometric Brownian motion

$()=_t_t+_tS_t_t$

using Ito's formula. Starting:

$d ln S_t = \frac{1}{S_t}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{S_t^{2}})(dS_t)^2$

Computing the following:

a) $\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{S_t^{2}}) = -\frac{1}{2S_t^{2}}$

b) $(_t_t+_tS_t_t)^2 = u^2S^2dt^2 + ^2S^2dW^2 - 2_t_t_tS_t_t$

Continuing with the term $(u^2S^2dt^2 + ^2S^2dW^2 - 2_t_t_tS_t_t)dt$

$dt^2=0 ,u^2S^2dt^2 $ disappears;

$dW^2 = dt, (^2S^2dW^2)dt$ leads to $dt^2$ and hence this term is 0 as well;

Last term $(2_t_t_tS_t_t)dt$ leads to zero as well if we would follow my reasoning above however this doesn't seem correct and the solution given is as follows:

$= \frac{1}{S_t}[_t_t+_tS_t_t]  -\frac{1}{2S_t^{2}}(_tS_t)^2dt$

$= (_t-\frac{1}{2}_t^{2})dt + _t_t$

Can someone explain to me

1) Where do I go wrong from step b where I try to eliminate terms and

2) How the last 2 steps are being calculated?

Comment: now you can integrate the result since you don't have the inconvenient $S_t$

Comment: What? Let's start with the first problem; can you eliminate the terms $(u^2S^2dt^2 + ^2S^2dW^2 - 2_t_t_tS_t_t)dt$?

Comment: we use the convergence over the variance to neglect terms higher than $dt$ terms like $dW\cdot dt$ are higher order terms. Also note that $\sigma^2S^2dW^2$ is the term it does not have a $dt$ term multiplying it as you have done above.

Comment: I am so sorry I fail to understand you. Are you perhaps able to work out the term $(dS_t)^2$ in steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you can apply Ito is to use
$$
f(S_t) = \ln S_t
$$
then we have
$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial S_t} dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial S_t^2} (dS_t)^2 =\frac{1}{S_t}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{S_t^2}dS_t^2
$$

We now need to compute $dS_t^2$

$$
dS_t^2 = \left(\mu_tS_tdt + \sigma_tS_tdW_t  \right)^2 = \sigma_t^2S_t^2dW_t^2 + 2\mu_t\sigma_tS_t^2dW_tdt + \mu_t^2S_t^2dt^2
$$
I have ordered the terms in order of $dt$. The first term is order $dt$ the other terms are all higher orders of $dt$ namely, $dW_tdt\sim dt^{3/2}$. We ignore terms higher than $dt$ as they vanish to zero faster than $dt$.

So we end up with
$$
df = \left(\mu_tS_tdt + \sigma_tS_tdW_t\right)\cdot \frac{1}{S_t} + \sigma_t^2S_t^2dt \cdot \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{S_t^2}
$$
or
$$
df = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dW_t + \frac{\sigma_t^2}{2}dt = \left(\mu_t + \frac{\sigma_t^2}{2}\right)dt + \sigma_tdW_t
$$

Comment: Yes! I am almost there computing the last steps. $
df = \left(\mu_tS_tdt + \sigma_tS_tdW_t\right)\cdot \frac{1}{S_t} + \sigma_t^2S_t^2dt \cdot \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{S_t^2}
$
Computing:
$\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{S_t^2} = \frac{1}{2S^2}$

$\frac{1}{S_t} \cdot(\mu_tS_tdt + \sigma_tS_tdW_t) = \frac{\mu_tS_tdt}{S_t} + \frac{\sigma_tS_tdWt}{S_t}$

Dividing by $S_t$ gives $\mu_td_t + \sigma_tdW_t$, so far so good?
Now moving on to the last part:
$\sigma_t^2S_t^2dt  \cdot \frac{1}{2S^2} = \frac{\sigma_t^2S_t^2dt}{2S^2}$, can you show me how you solved this?

Comment: you do the same, you can rearrange to obtain $$\frac{\sigma_t^2}{2}\cdot\frac{S_t^2}{S_t^2}\cdot dt$$ which you can cancel through.

Comment: Legend. I didn't see that at the moment. Thank you very much, now I can move on to complex SDE :)!