# Is $W^2-t$ martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion. Is $W^2-t$ martingale?
We start by taking the derivatives with respect to $t$ and $W_t$.

- 1) Defining f(t, X) = $X^2-t$.

$\frac{df(t,X)}{dt}$ = $-1$;
  $\frac{df(t,X)}{dX}$ = $2x$; $\frac{d^2f(t,X)}{dX^2}$ = $2$.

- 2) Using Ito's lemma:
  df = $\frac{df(t,X)}{dt}$(dt) + $\frac{df(t,X)}{dX}$(dX) + $\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2f(t,X)}{dX^2}(dX)^2$.
- 3) Substituting X = $W_t$ and the derivatives:
  df = -1dt + 2$W_t(dW_t)$ + $\frac{1}{2}2(dW_t)^2$
- 4) $(dW_t)^2 = (dW^2-t)^2 = (dW^4 -t^2 +2dW^2t)$

And from here I have massive problems obtain the desired solution

- = $2W_tdW_t$

I am quite confused when you need to substitute the full function $W^2-t$ in step 3.

At that moment, do we need to insert the derivative notation so like this : $dW^2-dt$ and then expand for the second derivative so ($dW^2-dt)^2$ and then expand power given us the following: ($dW^4-dt^2 + dW^2dt)$?

Can someone explain this to me and finish what I started in explicit derivation?

**Edit: I was given clear instructions to find the diffusion equation using Ito's lemma.**

Comment: I need Ito's lemma derivation for this problem.

Comment: I think OP is saying they would like to understand the Itô formula or are instructed to use it. Indeed, they are making a huge mistake: the Itô term is not literally $(dX)^2$. That is just a shorthand for the quadratic variation $[W]_s = s$, sometimes written $(dW_s)^2 = s$. Itô's formula actually gives $$f(W_t, t) - f(W_0, 0) = \int_0^t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} ds + \int_0^t \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dW_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(W_s) d[W]_s,$$ which is $$\int_0^t (-1) ds + \int_0^t 2W_s dW_s + \int_0^t (1) ds = \int_0^t 2W_s dW_s.$$

Comment: @snar Yes, this makes indeed sense. However, why do we insert the full process and calculating $(dX_t)^2$ in the following answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3453067 ? Can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you just made a simple substitution mistake. When you wrote
$$(dW_t)^2 = (dW - t)^2,$$
you actually substituted what you thought would be $dX_t$. But in fact, $X_t = f(t, W_t)$, and so the term $(dX)^2$ in your Ito formula corresponds to just $(dW_t)^2 = t$, as in the answer you linked in the comments. Indeed, there $f$ was a function of $S_t$ alone, and an expression for $dS_t$ was given. In your situation, you have an expression  in terms of $X_t = W_t^2 - t$ and it's just a question of evaluating $dX_t$.

Comment: I don't know how I've missed it, after your explanation and a nights sleep its a super simple problem to solve it, mucho gracias.

Comment: I have another question tho, lets say we have $f(t, X) = e^{X^2-t}$, do we still use only $(dX)^2 = dt $ in the second derivative of Ito's lemma?

Comment: We should avoid extended discussions in comments and if you have another question, post it. To briefly answer, first change notation since you are making it difficult for yourself and let $f(t, w)$ be the function such that $X_t = f(t, W_t)$ for a Wiener process $W_t$. Ito's formula is $$dX_t = \partial_t f(t, W_t) dt + \partial_w f(t, W_t) dW_t + (1/2)\partial_w^2 f(t, W_t) d[W_t],$$ where $[W_t] = t$ is the  *quadratic variation* of a Wiener process. If you want to use the shorthand $(dW_t)^2 = t$ to say that last part, I suppose no one can stop you.

Answer (score 0):

$W_{t}^{2}-t$ is a martingale. It can be easily proven using definition of martingale
and basic properties of Brownian motion. Why do You want to attack it with Ito's formula?

Comment: I know its a martingale because it doesn't have a drift term. However I need the explicit derivation for my own understanding using Ito's lemma.